# MobileFirst Studio Upgrade Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I just upgrade my current mobilefirst studio to latest version. After the Update i can't able to open the my projects.It's showing the following **error** when tried to open the project.

> "Migrating the ProjectName project from version 7.0.0.00.20150610-1353
>   to version 7.1.0.00.20150807-0630 has failed because  There is no
>   available migration path. Use the latest MobileFirst Studio or the
>   latest "IBM MobileFirst Studio Upgrader" from IBM Fix  Central site
>   http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/ "

Comment: Provide your project so it could be debugged and see if there is a defect or not.

Comment: It's working perfectly before the mobileFirst studio upgrades

Comment: Again, if you want help we need to reproduce the error. Provide a project that will allow us to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

This question is useless without providing a project that demonstrates the failure in upgrade in MobileFirst Studio.

As such, the only alternative I can offer is for you to create a new project in MobileFirst Studio, and copy over into it your web resources to the corresponding folders: the JavaScript, CSS and HTML, as well any custom classes you may have implemented.